# Apollo create new field base on two another

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have apollo type like this one:

```
Client {
 firstName
 lastName
}
```

Is there any option to create a separated field called `fullName` or build some helper which will be a part of apollo, and includes values of those 2 fields?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by extending schema locally: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/local-state/#define-a-client-side-schema